# Dispatching notification in correct activity

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have a problem with notification on Android (Xamarin).
My scenario is this:
I have a class handling (inheriting `GcmServiceBase`) the message and creating the Notification object.
In this class I override `OnMessage` method in this way:

```
protected override void OnMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent != null || intent.Extras != null)
    {
        string messageText = intent.Extras.GetString("message");
        string messageTitle = intent.Extras.GetString("title");
        Intent app_launch_intent = new Intent(context, typeof(Project.WaitForm));         
    if (App.Instance == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GCM: Notification received while application not running...");  
        app_launch_intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        app_launch_intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
    }

    else if ((App.Instance != null) && (App.Instance.mainActivity.IsInBackground))
    {
        App.Instance.Logger.Write("GCM: Notification received while application in background...", LogType.Default, LogLevel.Info);
        app_launch_intent = new Intent(context, App.Instance.mainActivity.GetType());
    }

    else
    {
        App.Instance.Logger.Write("GCM: Notification received while application in foreground...", LogType.Default, LogLevel.Info);
        app_launch_intent = new Intent(context, App.Instance.mainActivity.GetType());
        app_launch_intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
    }

    app_launch_intent.PutExtras(intent.Extras);
    app_launch_intent.PutExtra("isNotify", true);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, PushService.notificationId, app_launch_intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
    createNotification(context, app_launch_intent, pendingIntent, messageTitle, messageText);
    if (App.Instance == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("GCM: Notification object correctly created."); 
    }
    else
    {
        App.Instance.Logger.Write("GCM: Notification object correctly created.", LogType.Default, LogLevel.Info);
    }
    }
}

public void createNotification(Context context, Intent result_intent, PendingIntent pendingIntent,  string title, string desc)
{
    NotificationManager notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .SetAutoCancel(true)
    .SetContentTitle(title)
    .SetContentText(desc)
    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notify_icon_transparent)
    .SetLargeIcon(PushService.IconAgenda)
    .SetTicker(title);
Notification notification = builder.Build();
PushService.notificationId += 1;
notificationManager.Notify(PushService.notificationId, notification);
```

}

as you can see, when message is received I test if application object exists then I create Intent and notification object (`App.Instance` is a singleton holding informations about the app itself. `mainActivity` is the current activity shown on screen).

In this way when notification is clicked, last activity on the top of the stack (current on-screen activity if app is in foreground or last on-screen activity before app went in background) will come
 up and something in it will take care about notification itself, called by `OnNewIntent`.

Everything is working fine except for a thing:

Let's say I have 3 Activity called A, B, C.

I start the app and then I receive 2 different notifications when current activity on screen is A.
 Both will be displayed in the top bar without problems.
 I click on the first of them and it asks me to open another activity (catched in `OnNewEvent` of current activity and due to notification type), so I say "yes" and I will have a transition to activity C.

Once reached activity C and after done some work, I click on the other notification.

Clicking on it I will be carried to activity A and then notification will be handled.
 I know this "problem" is because at notify creation I use the `App.Instance.mainActivity.GetType()` to create intent that will be use to create `PendingIntent` and that at that time was activity A for both.
 So my question is:

How can I handle second notify click in last activity on screen (so in activity C) instead of activity A?

(I add Xamarin tag just because code above is in C# and not in Java so it may sound strange to a native Android developer)